# Does Google Analytics use the Referer field on Request Header?

Tags: google-analytics, http-referer, request-headers

I'm using google analytics on my site and I want to strip out all sensitive data like IDs.
I went with this approach where i strip out the referer from the request url

```
 ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'page': path,
    'location': '',  @* strip out *@
    'referrer': '' @* strip out *@
});
```

but it seems that some IDs still come through. I believe this is because of the actual Referer field on the Request Header itself. Does GA use the referer field off the request header when determining traffic? Can someone confirm this for me?

Answer (score 0):

yes Google uses referrer, but if you're over-riding it make sure you're override works properly you can cross check using firebug in firefox or in ga-debugger in chrome browser.

you can try following code:

```
ga('set', 'referrer', '');

ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': path
});
```

Comment: I'm overriding the referrer parameter in the request url, it's correctly set to nothing. But the request header still has a Referer field...can i override that?

Comment: nope that doesn't make a difference. The Referer in the Request header is still available.

Comment: You can't modify the request headers, but you can override referrer value in GA/UA for pageview call.

Comment: Does GA use the Request Header? Does it maybe check the referer value in the pageview call and if empty use the referer header value?

Comment: can you share your website url? or provide some example to give you better answer?

Comment: AFAIK the GA does not use HTTP referer header field. But it may be sniffed by some network components (proxies) on the way to the Google.